# Sqlite: How to enable "PRAGMA case_sensitive_like" on WP7

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, case-sensitive

I'm using Sqlite database on Windows Phone 7 platform and want to enable case sensitive searching, to do this I need to call "PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;".

I'm using the Vici CoolStorage assemblies to execute the queries and I want to execute this statement before the call to `RunQuery`.

```
CSConfig.SetDB(dirDatabaseFile, SqliteOption.None);
results = CSDatabase.RunQuery<PageIndex>(sql).ToList();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

CSDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery("PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON")